# How to solve a linear system with a close to zero eigenvalue?

Tags: matrix, system

The following is a small part of my research:

I got a 4 by 4 matrix $\mathbf{M}$ of rank 3:

```
M={{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, -2, 2.0006219879401477, -2.0006219879401477}, {4.193503236170054, 0.07680669095242888, 4.195764689057942, 0.0767525731461281}, {19.781537502364305, -0.36231149755725733, 19.793967330980973, -0.36208844823571257}}
```

I need to solve the system $\mathbf{MC=0}$ where $\mathbf{C}=[C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4]^\top$. I know that $\mathbf{M}$ has rank equal to 3, but due to computation error, Mathematica gives its rank equal to 4. (One can check using the command "Eigenvalues[M]" to find that one of its eigenvalues is very close to zero.)

I set $C_1=1$, and want to solve for $C_2,C_3,C_4$. I'm wondering if there is a way I can get a good approximation of $C_2,C_3,C_4$. I thought of using Gaussian Elimination, but I have no idea how to proceed, as I cannot change the fact that the rank is 4 in Mathemtaica.

Any help or hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: The `Tolerance` option of`NullSpace` is good for this situation. `In[2220]:= 
mat = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, -2, 
    2.0006219879401477, -2.0006219879401477}, {4.193503236170054, 
    0.07680669095242888, 4.195764689057942, 
    0.0767525731461281}, {19.781537502364305, -0.36231149755725733, 
    19.793967330980973, -0.36208844823571257}};
NullSpace[mat, Tolerance -> 10^(-6)]

Out[2221]= {{0.23992, -0.665256, -0.23978, 0.665115}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `NullSpace` gives exactly the same result as a `SingularValueDecomposition ` (see update in my solution) and seems much simpler!

Comment: @Roman As you may have guessed, indeed NullSpace for approximate values does use the SVD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
M = {{1, 1, 1, 1},
     {2, -2, 2.0006219879401477, -2.0006219879401477},
     {4.193503236170054, 0.07680669095242888, 4.195764689057942, 0.0767525731461281},
     {19.781537502364305, -0.36231149755725733, 19.793967330980973, -0.36208844823571257}};
```

Look for the eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue (by absolute value):

```
c = MinimalBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[M]], Abs@*First][[1, 2]]
(*    {0.240408, -0.66508, -0.240268, 0.664939}    *)
```

The result is pretty close to $M\cdot c=0$:

```
M . c
(*    {-3.98559*10^-7, 1.1026*10^-6, 3.98325*10^-7, -1.10236*10^-6}    *)
```

Normalizing by the first element $c_1=1$:

```
cn = Normalize[c, First]
(*    {1., -2.76646, -0.999414, 2.76587}    *)
```

If your matrix is large, you could speed things up by trying to compute only the smallest eigenvalue/eigenvector pair:

```
Eigensystem[M, -1]
(*    {{-1.65784*10^-6}, {{0.240408, -0.66508, -0.240268, 0.664939}}}    *)
```

and therefore

```
c = Eigenvectors[M, -1][[1]]
(*    {0.240408, -0.66508, -0.240268, 0.664939}    *)
```

## update: singular-value decomposition

On second thought, an eigenvalue decomposition may not be the best way forward and a more general singular-value decomposition could give a slightly more accurate result.

The singular value decomposition is

```
{u, σ, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[M];
```

Look for the smallest singular value by absolute magnitude:

```
s = OrderingBy[Diagonal[σ], Abs, 1][[1]]
(*    4    *)
```

The minimizing vector is the corresponding vector in $v$:

```
d = Transpose[v][[s]]
(*    {0.23992, -0.665256, -0.23978, 0.665115}    *)
```

See that it fits better:

```
{Norm[M . c], Norm[M . d]}
(*    {1.65784*10^-6, 5.37312*10^-7}    *)
```

Faster by computing only the smallest singular value by Arnoldi iteration:

```
d = SingularValueDecomposition[M, -1,
      Method -> {"Arnoldi",
                 "Criteria" -> "Magnitude",
                 "MaxIterations" -> 10^6}][[3, All, 1]]
(*    {-0.23992, 0.665256, 0.23978, -0.665115}    *)
```

Even faster and fully equivalent: compute the smallest eigenvalue and its associated eigenvector of $M^T\cdot M$: this is the vector that minimizes $\|M\cdot\vec{d}\|^2=\vec{d}\cdot (M^T\cdot M)\cdot \vec{d}$ under the constraint that $\|\vec{d}\|^2=\vec{d}\cdot\vec{d}=1$:

```
d = Eigenvectors[Transpose[M] . M, -1,
      Method -> {"Arnoldi",
                 "Criteria" -> "Magnitude",
                 "MaxIterations" -> 10^6}][[1]]
(*    {-0.23992, 0.665256, 0.23978, -0.665115}    *)
```